# Volley passing JSONobject as Parameters POST Method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using the Request class to do a POST request, to my server. I have to send some parameters with this. So i am doing like this.

```
private final Listener<String> mListener;
private Map<String, String> mParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ChangePwdRequest(int method, String username, String currentPwd,
        String newPwd, Listener<String> mListener, ErrorListener listener) {
    super(Method.POST, Utilites.CHANGEPWD_REQUEST_URL,listener);
    mParams.put("user_id", username);
    mParams.put("current_password", currentPwd);
    mParams.put("new_password", newPwd);
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    return mParams;
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

    Gson mGson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = new String(response.data);
    ChangePwdResponse cateResponse = mGson.fromJson(jsonString,
            ChangePwdResponse.class);
    return Response.success(cateResponse.result, getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}
```

I am getting the response from the server. It works fine.However if i want to send some JSONdata to my Post Call then i should use  [JsonRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonRequest.java)  . right ?

My question is 
1. As Request is the base class for all request is it possible to send parameters in Json here ?
2. When we send parameters using map as i am sending in the above code snippet, is it appended in the string later on ?

Comment: Is this class extending `Request` class?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. Using Request class you can directly override the `Map<String, String> getParams()` method and set the paramas in hashmap for post request.For setting JsonObject you may have to override getBody() instead, to return `jsonObj.toString().getBytes("utf-8")`. But I would suggest you to use `JsonObjectRequest` class or `StringObjectRequest` class, following the rule DRY.

Answer 2. It convert it to encoded String, convert it to byte array then open one connection object and write the byte array on the output stream of that connection object or set the entity in the HttpRequest object.

Digging the Volley source-code
In HurlStack class for api level => 9  in order to make `POST` request with body  `request.getBody()` method is called which return `[]byte` that is written on the output stream of the connection object.
In HttpClientStack class for api level<9, the byte array is set as an entity to the HttpEntity class.

```
 HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(request.getBody());
 httpRequest.setEntity(entity);
```